# Path-independant management of shared C libs inside a Python package

Tags: python, package, ctypes

Say I have a package called Foo organized this way:

```
Foo\
    __init__.py
    foo.py
    bar.py
    lib\
        libwhatever.so
```

My module foo.py uses python ctypes to wrap the C-methods contained in my libwhatever.lib, which involves checking the lib is where it should be. 2 questions:

1) How to check in my package that the required lib is at its place (in Foo\lib), wherever the entire Foo package has been placed ?

Right now, the path to my lib is hard-coded but, as I may distribute things later, the problem will come.

2) Then I have module bar.py which packs a slower Python version of the C-routines inside libwhatever. I would like to use them instead whether the import of libwhatever fails. Is there a way to abstractly switch between the C and Python version of the routines wrt the success or failure of the library importation ?

Thank you in advance for your advice.

Comment: for the bar.py vs lib.so, you can wrap the `import libwhatever` in a `try` / `except` clause.  If import fails, try to import `bar`

Comment: you mean when I do the ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(path_to_my_libwhatever) ?

Comment: Oh, im sorry, i forgot you were using ctypes, yeah.  If the file can't be found, it will raise `OSError` so you can just create an exception block for `OSError` and in that block, import bar.

Comment: Thanks. That's a good start for solving question 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're on Linux, I *think* you'll have to either add that .so file to your library search path, or add the module directory to your path. Have a look at ldconfig. `man ldconfig`. Once you do either of those, you could use `ctypes.util.find_library()`.  Otherwise you would have to have the full path to the .so file to use `cdll()`.

What I think I would do is just build that path at run time- so something kind of like this:

```
from ctypes import CDLL
import Foo
try:
    MyLib = CDLL(Foo.__path__[0] + '/lib/libwhatever.so')
except OSError:
    from Foo import bar as MyLib
```

Though, there may be a better way...

Comment: It's possible to the get full path to python file itself using `__FILE__` so from there he can figure out the exact path to the attempt to load the library from.

Comment: Indeed, my library will always be located in Foo/lib/, hence I just need to recover somehow the path to Foo and I am done. tMC's snippet seems to be doing just that.

Comment: @gvail awesome! if a better solution doesn't come along, can you select my answer? thanks!

Comment: Actually I used tMC's snippet with Joe's suggestion. __file__ gives me the path of the module from which I can extract the directory using os.path.dirname(). The try/catch block is effectively doing the smart switch between the 2 libs. Thank you guys for your help.